# Flash doesn't scale in Chrome

Tags: html, flash, google-chrome, scale

Here is the code html + js. for the page with the embeded swj movie. 
The settings for scaling are set to SHOW_ALL. It is done for zooming - when users zoom page in or out the flash movie changes its size to zoom with the page. Everything works perfectly for FF, but for Chrome it doesn't work. It starts working when I manually set the setting to Show All (right click on flash movie and then set setting).

Any ideas how I can fix this? 
Thank you a lot!

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Webcam Recording Demonstration</title>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flash.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="embedflash.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="flashinterface.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
       <div id="page-wrap">
        <div id="header">
            Demonstration of videorecording
        </div>
        <div id="content-wrap">
        <div id="flash-container">
            <div id="flashObject">          
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: block; clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    <div id="record" class="button">
        Record
    </div>
    <div id="play" class="button">
        Play
    </div>
        <div id="footer" >
        Designed and Implemeted by Petr Kaplunovich. MathJax package used
        </div>
    <div style="display: block; clear: both;"></div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function embedGuy(){
    var swfVersionStr = "0";
    var xiSwfUrlStr = "";
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {};
    params.quality = "best";
    params.bgcolor = "#f1f1f1";
    params.play="true";
    params.loop="true";
    params.wmode="window";
    params.scale="showall";
    params.menu="true";
    params.salign="";
    params.devicefont="false";
    params.allowScriptAccess = "always";//"sameDomain";
    params.allowFullScreen="true";
    params.movie="webcam.swf";
    var attributes = {};
    attributes.id = "webcam";
    attributes.name = "webcam";
    attributes.align = "middle";
    swfobject.embedSWF(
    "webcam.swf", "flashObject",
    "100%", "100%",
    swfVersionStr, xiSwfUrlStr,
    flashvars, params, attributes);
}
embedGuy();
```

P.S. I have already tried to control settings directly from flash - unfortunately nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Your flash-container div is blocking the embedded Flash from expanding.

If you change flash-container width and height to 100% then it expands as you zoom the page in Chrome.